# Do I have to explicitly create a USDC account to be able to receive USDC coins?

Tags: spl-token, associated-token-account, spl-associated-token-account, associated-token-program

I have a Solana (#1) and USDT (#2) adddresses on the same account. I have some USDT coins in it. There's no USDC, though.

I've already sent some USDC to the #1 in testnet, from a faucet, but none of them has arrived.

I'm aware that in Solana, unlike Ethereum, for instance, an address for a token has to be generated first in order to activate it, and it has its own address. Right? But I haven't generated one for USDC.

Is this a reason that none of the USDC coins has arrived? How will I generate one if not in wallet app?

Is there the official online service of Solana that'll generate an associated address by the address of the main - SOL - one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send USDC to a wallet address, the sender has to pay to create the linked token account (USDC associated token account for this particular wallet address). if the said token account already exists, of course there is nothing to pay anymore.

What is your wallet address ? You can check on explorer / solscan if there are USDC linked to this wallet address.

You should not have to create it by yourself.

Are you sure that #1 is a wallet address ?

One other reason could be that the faucet you are using doesn't create associated token account, but seems unlikely IMO. What is this tool address btw ?

Comment: Approximately how much is a fee that a sender will pay  for creating an assosiated token account of a receiver?

Comment: When i take a look at one of my associated token accounts, there are roughly 0.002 SOL in it (rent free fees), so i guess that's the amount the sender has to fund if this token accoutn doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not.

Sending some USDC to that address should do this for you. Most wallets will do this for you.

Also, make sure that the signer has some sol to cover the tx fees.

Answer (score 0):

All Sol wallets can internally create the token account when the wallet receives the token.
The sending wallet/signer should have the SOL to cover the tx fees.

If you are unable to see the USDC in your wallet, try to manage tokens and paste the token address to view the token in your wallet.

Solana doesn't provide an official app to generate an associated address.
But they provide web3 client library, you can build from it.
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/javascript-api

Comment: no, i don't think a wallet (like phantom) create any account for you when you *receive* stuff. May be it creates account when you *send*, but not when you receive, i think that's not even possible (you can't even receive if the account doesn't exists...)